# P/Invoke errors only on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, pinvoke

I have ASP.NET MVC3 application that uses some methods from crypt32.dll using P/Invoke. Everything works fine on Windows XP, Windows 7 (both 32bit and 64bit), Windows Server 2003 (also 32bit and 64bit) but my troubles started when I tried setting the application on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. Further, when I try to run the project from VS2010 on that same machine, it works fine. Server has latest updates installed, IIS 7.5 and all the other stuff needed.

Application is not giving any error, but just results in "Page not available" or sometimes Error 503 (stopping the application pool).

Here is what I get in Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: CRYPT32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b841
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00010cf3
Faulting process id: 0xc4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd3f0fac5721fb
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
Report Id: ee39118a-ab02-11e1-8d06-000c297e9eda
```

Application pool is used just by this application, it is set to enable 32bit applications, integrated pipeline and correct .Net version. Project is built for x86 platform (even I tried every other possibility) and I even tried to add required DLLs to project, setting Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always, but nothing helps.

Using logs I managed to figure out it breaks at:

```
if (!CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, IntPtr.Zero, ref cbData))
{
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

DLLImport code:

```
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(
    IntPtr pCertContext,
    uint dwPropId,
    IntPtr pvData,
    ref uint pcbData
);
```

Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Here is the rest of the code:

```
CERT_NAME_BLOB cnbCertificate;
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB certificate;
IntPtr hCertStore = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pCertContext = IntPtr.Zero;
uint cbData = 0;

byte[] encoded = Encode(cert.Subject);

GCHandle pinnedArray = new GCHandle();
pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(cBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

certificate.cbData = cBuffer.Length;
certificate.pbData = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
pinnedArray.Free();
hCertStore = PFXImportCertStore(ref certificate, password, CRYPT_USER_KEYSET | CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);
cnbCertificate.cbData = (uint)encoded.Length;
GCHandle h1;

if (hCertStore != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    try
    {
        h1 = GCHandle.Alloc(encoded, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        cnbCertificate.pbData = h1.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        dataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(cnbCertificate, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_NAME, dataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), IntPtr.Zero);
        if (h1 != null) h1.Free();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        log.Error("Marshall error1: " + exp.Message + " " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

if (!CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, IntPtr.Zero, ref cbData))
{
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Comment: Why are you using P/Invoke instead of the built-in certificate classes like X509Certificate2 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx ?

Comment: Using X508Certificate2 is not an option here for multiple reasons, one of them is that I need RC4 algorithm, which is not supported by .NET framework

Comment: What does RC4 have to do with the certificate? Anyway, what is the error in the log? Since you are throwing the exception yourself, you should be looking at CertGetCertificateContextProperty and the context you are using, not ASP.NET or P/Invoke. What is the error code? Is it one of the error codes mentioned in the function documentation? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer. What log? Browser is trowing Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown Error, in my log file there is no error, and I only get this one from IIS that I already posted. This call for CertGetCertificateContextProperty is inside try-catch clause, but it does not enter catch part and it won't get to Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); part inside if clause either. It seems like it just stops IIS. Thanks for helping anyway, and sorry if I'm not explaining this well. Again, context has to be good and this same code works on every other platform.

Comment: Please explain the down votes, I really think this guy has a legit Q, you know just a DebugDiag comment or something.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed the Exception code: 0xc0000005 in the log. That's an access violation which means that the pointer you provide to the method refers to an invalid address. The pointer itself may be null or zero, or the [CERT_CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure it should point to has invalid data.

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or IIS, there is an error in the code or the data. Perhaps the certificate is wrong to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice Exception code: 0xc0000005 before, but it did not make my life any easier. I'm using my own log to see what exactly is happening, and it seems like it enters CertGetCertificateContextProperty for the first time and then for no reason goes to the start of that same controller. When it comes to the same place for the second time it gives that access vilation error, which makes sense since this time certificate is not loaded as it should. Does this makes any sense? What might cause this. Certificate is tested, it is working.

Comment: Also, when I try debugging code on the same machine, with the same files, it works fine. That is what made me think it has something to do with IIS or Win 2008 configuration.

Comment: to look up those error codes: http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985 put the exe in your sys32 folder then you can run it from cmd (regardless of location) eg cmd > err 0xc0000005 and this will tell you the OS Error and it is easier to google.com the EM than hex code,

Comment: Thanks Jeremy but it seems like the error I get is caused because of the scenario I described in previous comment (entering same controller twice). Also, I just tried setting the same app on Windows Server 2008 x64 and it works fine, so this problem is exclusive to R2 edition...

Comment: No, it is not. It is exclusive to your code, using the specific data on the specific machine. You have an access violation, because you are passing a bad pointer. In this case the OS kills the offending process immediately because the process memory has become suspect. Check the data structure you are passing to the function or the pointer to the function. Or at least post the code where you are creating the structure

Comment: I posted the rest of the code, can you please check if there is something wrong with it. Thanks